# При попытке обращения к Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel вылетает исключение

Tags: c#, excel

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app;
}
```

При попытке компиляции этого простого кода вылетает исключение:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Вы уверены, что правильно референс добавили в приложение?

Comment: Я добавил сначала через COM, выбрал там Microsoft Excel Object Library и Microsoft Office Object Library. Не сработало - вылетает исключение. Потом добавил через NuGet, предварительно убрав эти две ссылки. Тоже ничего, та же самая ошибка.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects